# ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>

Tags: tables

can anybody help me for this kind of problem?

**! Missing number, treated as zero.**

```
\documentclass[DIV=12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array, caption, makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}



\begin{document}


\begin{table}[hbt!]
\small
\centering
\captionabove{Relation analysis\label{ft}}
\begin{tabular}{|c||*{7}{wc{1.0cm}|}}
\hline
Parameters of output&
\multicolumn{7}{c|}{Characteristicss}\\[1ex]
\cline{2-8}
& \makecell{max.\\ accel.\\ [m s$^{-2}$]} & \makecell{min.\\ accel.\\[m s$^{-2}$]} &Peak &\makecell{Energy\\[$J$]} &\makecell{Dom.\\ freq.\\[$Hz$]} &RMS&\makecell{Event\\ durat.\\[$s$]} \\
\hline
Angular frequency & \cellcolor{red!100}$+++$ & $---$&$+++$& $+++$&$+++$                    & $+++$& $---$\\\hline
Amplitude & \cellcolor{red!60}$+++$ & $---$&$+++$& $+++$&\cellcolor{green!80}$Nan$      & $+++$& $--$\\\hline
Exponential decay coeff. & \cellcolor{red!37}1 & 1&1& 1&\cellcolor{green!80}$Nan$                               & 1& 1\\\hline
Rise time coeff. & \cellcolor{red!10} 1 & 1&1& 1& \cellcolor{green!80} $Nan$                                        & 1& 1\\\hline
Max time interval & \cellcolor{red!2}1 & 1&1& 1&\cellcolor{green!80}$Nan$                                           & 1& 1\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\\ [m s$^{-2}$]
```

`\\` has an optional argument giving extra vertical space like `\\[3pt]`  so in your case you need to "hide" the `[` so it is not taken as an argument.

```
\\{} [m s$^{-2}$]
```

would work for example.

Comment: Thank you very very much Sir